# Disable focus effect when not hovered

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I've got to create our own buttons using Bootstrap's `btn` class. I need to override default colors for the button text in particular. I know about `.button-variant` but I cannot use it (the corresponding LESS file is not included in project build and I can't make such changes). Here is my LESS:

```
.some-company-control(@text-color, @hover-text-color) {
  color: @text-color;

  &:hover,
  &:active {
    color: @hover-text-color;
  }
}
```

The problem is after a button is clicked it gets the default Bootstrap button text color. When I add `&:focus` it overrides Bootstrap's defaults but after it is clicked and not hovered it still remains as if it is clicked. I would like to disable the styling when a button is still focused but not hovered anymore.

Thanks everyone for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add this rule:

```
    &:focus:not(:hover) {
      color: @text-color;
    }
```